# Example function $f:(0,1) \to (0,1)$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is uncountable for all $y$.

Tags: real-analysis

Intuitively the interval $(0,1)$ can be an uncountable union of disjoint uncountable sets, but I'm wondering if there is a nice function to show this easily. Namely, what is a simple example of $f:(0,1) \to (0,1)$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is uncountable for every $y$?

Comment: You can even find a continuous function with this property: Just compose Peano curve with a coordinate projection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$f(0.x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5\ldots)=0.x_1x_3x_5\ldots$

Comment: This function is ill-defined. $f(0.55)\neq f(0.54999999\ldots).$

Comment: If we don't consider decimal representations ending with 9's as arguments, then it is well-defined.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say ill-defined as much as the function isn't fundamentally dependent in the quantities it's given but rather how they are expressed.

Comment: It's an example of a function that differentiates quantities in different representations

Comment: @user7530: That's irrelevant. Simply pick one infinite decimal expansion for each real.

Comment: @studiosus Sure, but the $f$, as written, doesn't do that.

Comment: This function is more easily defined as $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ and needs to choose a specific decimal representation for the function argument when the representation is ambiguous, but it fits the bill. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is known that there is a bijection $f:(0,1)\times (0,1)\to (0,1)$. Let $g:(0,1)\to (0,1)$ be a function defined as $g(f(x,y))=y$. Its domain is $(0,1)$ because $f$ is onto, and $f$ is well-defined because $f$ is one-to-one. It is easy to check that $\{z:g(z)=r\}$ is uncountable for each $r$.